# Inverse of a Digamma/ Polygamma Function

Tags: special-functions, inverse

How one can find the inverse of a digamma/ Polygamma function in Mathematica 10?

Comment: There isn't a closed form for the inverse, although one can build a numerical approximation. I presume you only want to invert the part corresponding to positive arguments?

Answer (score 2):

```
inversePolyGamma[y_] := x /. FindRoot[y == PolyGamma[x], {x, 1}];
Show[
   Plot[PolyGamma[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], 
   Plot[inversePolyGamma[y], {y, -3, 1}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Bill. I appreciate your effort.